# Method not found in Visual Studio Extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

When loading the GitStash Plugin into Visual Studio 2015 I get the follow errors.

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void  GitStash.ViewModels.RecommendedActionsViewModel..ctor(GitWrapper.IGitStashWrapper, TeamExplorer.Common.ITeamExplorerBase)'. at GitStash.Sections.RecommendedActionsSection.Initialize(Object sender, SectionInitializeEventArgs e) at  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.Framework.TeamExplorerSectionHost.Initialize(Object context)
>
> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void GitStash.ViewModels.StashesViewModel..ctor(GitWrapper.IGitStashWrapper, TeamExplorer.Common.ITeamExplorerBase, SecondLanguage.Translator)'.
>      at GitStash.Sections.StashesSection.Initialize(Object sender, SectionInitializeEventArgs e) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.Framework.TeamExplorerSectionHost.Initialize(Object context)

I downloaded the source (https://github.com/scrubs767/GitStash) and compiled and ran and was able to get the extension to run just fine in the experimental version of Visual Studio created by the debugger.

I'm not sure how else to debug this, it seems a few other people are having issues, but the maintainer(and myself) cannot reproduce the issue.

https://github.com/scrubs767/GitStash/issues/6

Is there any way I can track this down or begin to debug it?

EDIT

So I ran Fuslogvw.exe in accordance with this  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586219/visual-studio-extension-vspackage-runs-in-all-experimental-instances-but-does?rq=1)

The results I got back are in this  [gist](https://gist.github.com/bmeverett/6d0fa03590f380844aeb70dc0ec5c7e4)

It seems to be not loading the main GitStash extension/dll

https://gist.github.com/bmeverett/6d0fa03590f380844aeb70dc0ec5c7e4

Comment: I'm blind and can't read your screen shot.  How about just putting the text of the error in your question instead of a screenshot?

Comment: Does your VS ActivityLog.xml help at all ?

Comment: @GregTrevellick it seems that it's not loading the main dll of the VS Extension. I would assume this might be an issue with the installation which would be a Microsoft problem.

Comment: Since I'm the owner of the project I have some insight, it appears that some people have an issue with loading the main dll, my gut feeling is not that dll, but another dependant dll, there were a number, I have trimmed that down to just one, the libgitstash2.dll and of course its native binaries. I believe on some machines this is the issue. My biggest problem is not being able to reproduce the error on any machine I have access to.